# If I borrow a Battlefield 4 disc copy and then buy a different disc copy, will I have to re-install it, using even more PS4 space?

Tags: battlefield-4

I heard BF4 is like 40g to download, and while I have a good amount of space, I don't want to download the game and its updates twice. Will I have to re-install it all again, or can I pop the new disc in and it'll be all ready to go from when I last downloaded it all?

Answer (score 3):

No you will not need to re-install Battlefield 4 if you are using a different disk since the information installed on your PS4 is not tied to a single disk. You just need the disk to actually start the game. So you are fine if you buy your own copy.